# make node js listen to different port

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted node js to listen to a port, so i used the below code

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Regardless of what i use in `.listen` its listening to port number `1337`

Comment: downvoters, care to drop a comment on what should be improved

Comment: Sounds like a stupid question but have you restarted your server after making changes? :)

Comment: yes i did 
and I am a beginner to node js and i am facing this issue 
if its so simple, i think they should provide a solution instead of downvoting :)
because, i have explained the problem with my code clearly and this question is not a duplicate of any other question either. beginners might face the same issue again in future :)

Comment: Okay, I upvoted. (no idea who and why downvoted it.)  The code looks fine to me. I don't think there is any issue with your code. Please make sure you're runnint the right code. Sometimes, out of panic, we miss out on obvious things. :)

Comment: Thanks :) 
yeah, I think I am misplacing these lines in the app.js file

Comment: As a second thought, since you've provided `hostname` parameter, try changing your listen statement to `.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1",null,null);` or to  just `.listen(3000);`

Comment: Please don't drastically change your questions otherwise other people who have the same issue you do will be confused by the answers below that reference things no longer in your current version of the question.